# What does default Ant configuration look like in IntelliJ IDEA IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

I want to know how IntelliJ IDEA builds my module by default when no build tool is used.

I am building a simple module - a Java FX application.
The project layout is trivial from what I know:

- src/main/java - the source code
- src/main/resources - the resources
- bin/com.sankdev0.portfolio - the build output

The layout is shown on this pic:
[the project layout as seen in Project tab in IntelliJ IDEA window][1]

I do not use any build tool. However, when I do the build I get the following build output:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Parsing java... [`com.sankdev0.portfolio`]
Writing classes... [`com.sankdev0.portfolio`]
Checking dependencies... [`com.sankdev0.portfolio`]
Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
Updating dependency information... [`com.sankdev0.portfolio`]
Adding `@NotNull` assertions... [`com.sankdev0.portfolio`]
Adding pattern assertions... [`com.sankdev0.portfolio`]
Running 'after' tasks
javac 15.0.1 was used to compile java sources
Finished, saving caches...
Executing post-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Synchronizing output directories...
08.12.2020 1:11 - Build completed successfully with 1 warning in 2 sec, 50 ms
```

The output is on the picture:
[the build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEOAx.jpg)

So, if IntelliJ IDEA uses Ant, what is the default Ant config and where is it?
I've searched for it, no luck. I only get information on creating my own Ant build file.

Comment: It's not using Ant even if you see these messages. You can disable Ant plug-in in the IDE settings and still have the same results. What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA uses incremental compiler with `javac` backend from the JDK to compile your app and [Artifact configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) to package it. What exactly do you need to know and why?

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you for the help, I'll look into it. I think you've answered my question in essence. To be honest, I was using Eclipse without build tools trying to make my modular app see the static resources placed in a folder separate of the package. That was my actual problem, and I just couldn't get it. Then yesterday I tried out IntelliJ and it just worked. I spotted those messages and thought IntelliJ aided me in a way with Ant (I didn't use Ant). Again, thanks.